# Обособляются ли обороты со словом "вкупе"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли отделять запятыми оборот со словом *вкупе*? К примеру:

> *Внутренняя сила(,) вкупе с физической выносливостью(,) сделали его железным человеком.*

Comment: *Все вкупе принялись за дело* - нет запятых. О каком обороте Вы говорите?

Comment: Нет, не о таком. _Внутренняя сила(,) вкупе с физической выносливостью(,) сделали его железным человеком._ Что-то вроде этого.

Comment: В этом предложении оборот лучше обособить. С одной стороны, мы таким образом подчеркиваем его значимость, а с другой - при обособлении оброта предложение легче  (естественнее) читается.

Comment: А я бы не стал обособлять в этом случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны.

ВКУПЕ. I. нареч. Разг. Вместе. Все в. принялись за дело. Пожертвования в. составляют немалую сумму. II. **предлог.** с кем-чем. Вместе с кем-, чем-л. Отвечать буду в. со всеми.

**1) Это наречие (не обособляется):**

Такое беззастенчивое присвоение и прибавочного продукта и ренты **вкупе―** вызов самой природе рыночной экономики и духу гражданского общества.

Обособление предложных оборотов зависит от структуры предложения, а также от желания автора выделить эту падежную форму.

**2) Обособленный предложный оборот:**

Сиротливо валяющаяся на дне раковины столовая ложка, испачканная кашей, **вкупе с остатками запеканки,** места для других версий не оставляла. [Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)]

**3) Необособленный предложный оборот:**

Именно яблочный пирог **вкупе с распитой на двоих бутылкой дешевого хереса**, обнаруженной в одном из хозяйских шкафов, окончательно их помирил. [Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын (2014)]

Comment: А как разграничивать второй и третий случаи? Есть какое-то правило, или всё зависит от желания автора?

Comment: Чаще зависит от  структуры предложения. В предложении 2 перед предложным оборотом стоит  обособленное определение, а в предложении 3 - "пирог вкупе с бутылкой" читается как единая конструкция.

Comment: У Марининой явно не стыкуются времена причастия "валяющаяся" (наст.) и  глагола "оставляла" (прош.): надо было "валявшаяся", иначе с точки зрения наблюдателя валяющееся в текущий момент и впервые увиденное ранее не оставляло иных версий у того же наблюдателя, что странно. А поскольку этот фрагмент не выглядит эталоном русской словесности, ссылка на данного литератора не вполне убедительна. Обособление же оборота здесь указывает на то, что ложка "валялась вкупе с кашей" (т. е. не сиротливо), а не испачкана была сложным образом (кашей вкупе с остатками запеканки).

Comment: Второе логически менее противоречиво, однако не требует обособления (возможно, это корректор понял всё в первом смысле и обособил оборот)..

Answer (score 2):

Обособления никакого не нужно. *Вкупе* означает то же, что и *вместе*. Обособление возможно только в том случае, если этот оборот внедряется посреди предложения и его можно опустить без потери общего смысла.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Внутренняя сила(,) вкупе с физической выносливостью(,) сделали его железным человеком.***
>
> Нужно ли отделять запятыми оборот со словом *вкупе*?

**Нет, не нужно.**

Более того: при множественном числе сказуемого (*"сделали"*) обособление данного оборота будет ошибкой.

Ну а само предложение, на мой взгляд, вполне корректно. См. похожий пример:

*Лорель засмеялась, жизненная сила вкупе с эльфийской магией **убрали** полностью седину, морщины, фигура больше не горбилась под тяжестью прожитых лет.*

Comment: Везде, где описывается такое явление как подлежащее, представленное словосочетанием со значением совместности, приводятся примеры типа *А с Б*. Нигде не видел *А вместе с Б* или *А вкупе с Б.*

Comment: _М_Г: нигде не видел..._ === И о чём это говорит?

Comment: Это приглашение к разговору. Если Вы видели - скажите где.

Comment: Вот нашел: Словосочетания со значением совместности. Такие словосочетания называют равноправных участников совместного действия. Главное слово — существительное или местоимение в именительном падеже, зависимое — существительное в творительном падеже с **предлогом «с»:** (https://grammatika-rus.ru/glavnaya/sintaksicheskij-razbor/razbor-slovosochetaniya/)

Comment: Еще: Одним из видов цельных словосочетаний с общим значением совместности являются сочетания существительных или местоимений, объединенных **предлогом с**: мать с сыном (http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/tselnyie-slovosochetaniya-68307.html)

Comment: 5. Словосочетания со значением СОВМЕСТНОСТИ.
Такие словосочетания называют равноправных участников совместного действия). Главное слово — существительное или местоимение в именительном падеже, зависимое — существительное в творительном падеже с **предлогом С**:
брат с сестрой, Коля с товарищем, мы с приятелем. (http://lik-bez.com/board/sintaksis/slovosochetanie/45)

Comment: Простите, но я не понимаю, что именно Вы хотели бы обсудить: возможность употребления устарелого  слова  _вкупе_, корректность множ. числа глагола или же допустимость/недопустимость выделения оборота с _вкупе_ при множ. числе глагола? Для меня очевидно одно: в том предложении, что было в комментарии представлено Человеком, запятые недопустимы. Никаких _двух вариантов_ здесь быть не может. Множ. число глагола полностью отметает _второй вариант._

Comment: Вопрос о корректности множ. числа сказуемого. Сказуемое ставится во мн. ч. при подлежащем, представленном словосочетанием со значением совместности, типа *А с Б сидели на трубе*. Но под определение *словосочетание со значением совместности* попадает только пара с предлогом *с*. А в случае *А вкупе с Б* требуется сказуемое в ед.ч.

Comment: Я оформил все это в виде отдельного вопроса. Приглашаю туда.

Comment: Хорошо, вечером туда загляну.

Answer (score 0):

> Внутренняя сила(,) вкупе с физической выносливостью(,) сделали его железным человеком.

По-моему, обособление этого оборота зависит от решения автора.

В любом случае сказуемое во вножественном числе вряд ли корректно грамматически, а в единственном числе (внутренняя сила... **сделала**) преуменьшает значение физической выносливости как составляющей "железного человека".

Comment: Предложение придумывалось из головы, причём довольно быстро, поэтому и получилась неразбериха. Думаю, вы правы.